# How to get all digits of the Int value

Tags: swift, swift3

Is it possible to get all digits of the `Int` variable in the Swift not converting this variable to the `string` ?

Small example how i am doing this now:

```
let number = 123456

let array = String(number).characters.map{Int(String($0)) ?? 0}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var number = 123456
var array = [Int]()

while number > 0 {
    array.append(number % 10)
    number = number / 10
}
array.reverse()
```

Comment: Here's a one-liner, though it's probably less efficient than your original: `let array = (0...Int(ceil(log10(Float(number)))) - 1).reversed().map{(number / Int(NSDecimalNumber(decimal: pow(10, $0)))) % 10}`